# Is there a happens before relationship between the use of a stack local object and the destruction of the object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory-model, stdatomic

I watched this Herb Sutter talk: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Cpp-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-atomic-Weapons-2-of-2

Around the 1:25 mark, he talks about why the decrement of an atomic reference counter of a shared pointer requires acquire-release memory ordering.

The logic in the video is as follows:

1. There are two threads, both calling fetch_sub at same time.
2. Thread 1 has a use of the object before the decrement. It decrements the reference counter from 2 to 1.
3. Thread 2 decrements from 1->0, and deletes the control block pointer.

The reason for acquire/release being necessary is stated to be that the use of the object in thread 1 could be reordered below the decrement in thread 1 from the perspective of thread 2. Then thread 2 would decrement from 1->0 and delete the object before line A has happened.

Here is the slide:
[image]

But in a shared pointer implementation, the destructor (ignoring copy assignment, and manual release) does not use the object before the decrement. That means that a function call on the object of the shared pointer would have to be reordered after the destruction of the shared pointer.

It's very confusing to me how this is possible. Here are the specific questions I have:

1. Is it really possible for a destructor to be reordered before the use of an object? Let's say you had a unique pointer instead of a shared pointer. If the destructor of the unique ptr was reordered before its use, then you would be accessing deleted memory. That can't be right.
2. Why does it matter whether line A in thread 1 in the slide appears below thread 1's decrement *from the perspective of thread 2*? Assuming within thread 1 line A appears above the decrement, then won't the object state be updated and any side effects of the function call become apparent to thread 2 once the cache line is pushed to its processor? The code only runs on one thread. The relevant line on the slide is: 'To thread 2, line A could appear to move below thread 1's decrement'.

Answer (score 3):

Herb Sutter definitely knows his stuff, but I generally do not like it if one argues about possible "reorderings", because such arguments usually don't provide the full details why a reordering is actually possible. The C++ standard says *nothing* about if or when instructions can be reordered. It only defines a "happens-before" relation, and any reorderings that may be applied are ultimately a result of applying the rules for the happens-before relation (and of course the ubiquitous "as-if"-rule).

Why is this so important? Because the happens-before relation is also the basis for the definition of a data race:

> Two expression evaluations conﬂict if one of them modifies a memory location (4.4) and the other one reads or modifies the same memory location. [..]
>
> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conﬂicting actions, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither **happens before** the other [..]

And as we all know, data races result in UB, so any argument about correctness of multi-threaded code using atomics has to be based on happens-before. That is, which happens-before relations are required, and how are they established.

---

So let's take a look at the example:

```
Thread 1:
... // use object
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  // branch not taken
}

Thread 2:
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  delete control_block_ptr;
}
```

Your requirement here is that the `delete` must *happen-after* the use.

Suppose the object contains a `std::string` and thread 1 assigns a value to that string, i.e., we have a *write operation*. When thread 2 deletes the object, we also need to delete string member, which obviously involves at least a *read operation*. This is a textbook example of conflicting operations, so we have to ensure that the assignment in thread 1 *happens-before* the destruction, because otherwise we would have a data race! Using only memory_order_release, the fetch_sub operation cannot synchronize-with anything (a release-operation by itself is practically pointless), so no happens-before relation exists.

How can we fix it? By making sure that the operations on `refs` synchronize-with each other. If we use `memory_order_acq_rel`, then the `fetch_sub` in thread 2 synchronizes-with the `fetch_sub` in thread 1, thereby establishing a happens-before relation. "use object" is sequenced-before the `fetch_sub` in thread 1, and the `fetch_sub` in thread 2 is sequenced-before the `delete`. Thus we have:

- `t1.use -sb-> t1.fetch_sub -sw-> t2.fetch_sub -sb-> t2.delete`

where `-sb->` denotes "sequenced-before" and `-sw->` "synchronizes-with". And because happens-before is transitive, this implies that `t1.use` happens-before `t2.delete`.

Another solution would be to add an additional `refs.load(memory_order_acquire)` right before the `delete`, then we could stick with `memory_order_release` for the `fetch_sub`, because then the t2.load would synchronize-with the t1.fetch_sub.

**Update**

This update is due to the questions by @plasmacel in the comments.

The standard states the following (see [[intro.races]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/intro.races#14)):

> If an operation *A* that modifies an atomic object *M* happens before an operation *B* that modifies *M*, then *A* shall be earlier than *B* in the modification order of *M*.
>
> If a value computation *A* of an atomic object *M* happens before a value computation *B* of *M*, and *A* takes its value from a side effect *X* on *M*, then the value computed by *B* shall either be the value stored by *X* or the value stored by a side effect *Y* on *M*, where *Y* follows *X* in the modification order of *M*.
>
> If a value computation *A* of an atomic object *M* happens before an operation *B* that modifies *M*, then *A* shall take its value from a side effect *X* on *M*, where *X* precedes *B* in the modification order of *M*.
>
> If a side effect *X* on an atomic object *M* happens before a value computation *B* of *M*, then the evaluation *B* shall take its value from *X* or from a side effect *Y* that follows *X* in the modification order of *M*.

So this should make clear that the happens-before relation is not a property of the observable behavior, but rather *defines* the behavior (and therefore what is observable).

Without a happens-before relation, the only guarantee we have is that writes will become visible *eventually*, but not when or in which order. Without such guarantees, cross-thread communication is *very* limited.

However, above all there is the ubiquitous "as-if" rule, which allows the compiler to perform any and all optimizations as long as they do not affect the observable behavior. With respect to the happens-before relation this means the compiler is free to reorder operations (and therefore invalidate the happens-before relation), *iff* such a change cannot be observed by anyone.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
int x, y;

// Thread 1
x = 1;
y = 2;
```

Clearly, `x = 1` is sequenced-before `y = 2` and therefore `x = 1` should *happen before* `y = 2`, so one might assume that these operations cannot be reordered. However, reordering these assignments does not affect observable behavior from the perspective of Thread 1, so according to the as-if rule the compiler is free to do so. If another thread would read both variables, it could theoretically be able to observe such a change. But since the variables are not atomic, this would be a data race and therefore undefined behavior. So the compiler can safely assume that no other thread will read these variables while we are performing these writes.

Now let's make the variables atomic to avoid the data race so another thread can actually read the values:

```
std::atomic<int> x, y;

// Thread 1
x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
y.store(2, std::memory_order_relaxed);

// Thread 2
int a = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
int b = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Thread 1 first writes to `x` and then to `y`, while Thread 2 first loads `y` and then `x`, so one might assume that when Thread 2 reads `y == 2`, that it is guaranteed that it also reads `x == 1`. However, since all operations are relaxed, there are no guarantees in which order operations on different objects become visible. For example, there are systems (ARM, Power) where, due to the quirky memory subsystem architecture, the second write can become visible before the first. So even though `x.store` is sequenced before `y.store`, the write to `y` can become visible first.  But then the compiler can just as well reorder the two stores, because we would not be able to distinguish such a reorderings from the case were writes become visible in different order. And following the same argument, we could also reorder the two load operations.

Now let's try with a release:

```
std::atomic<int> x, y;

// Thread 1
x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
y.store(2, std::memory_order_release);

// Thread 2
int a = y.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
int b = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

A release-store synchronizes-with an acquire-store, thereby establishing a happens-before relation. However, it is important to note that we need *both sides*! A release-operation by itself achieves nothing. In this example, we have a release-store, but no acquire-operation. The loads are both still relaxed, so the compiler could still reorder them, based on the same argument as before. So essentially we still have no guarantees about the values Thread 2 reads! Assuming we have no other code accessing `x` and `y`, this basically means the compiler would also be free to reorder the *stores*, even though one of them uses `memory_order_release`. If the compiler can *prove* that a release-operation cannot synchronize with any acquire-operation, then it can never participate in any happens-before relation and therefore cannot provide any visibility guarantees, so essentially it is not stronger than a relaxed operation. I don't think any compiler actually does this (not just because such a proof would be difficult for any non-trivial code), but it would be valid.

So why do release/acquire-operations usually prevent reordering? Because when they *do* participate in a happens-before relation, some reorderings would indeed change observable behavior.

```
std::atomic<int> x, y, z;

// Thread 1
x.store(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
y.store(2, std::memory_order_release);
z.store(3, std::memory_order_relaxed);

// Thread 2
int c = z.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
int a = y.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
int b = x.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
```

Suppose `y.load` observes the value written by `y.store`, then the two operations synchronize with each other and thereby establish a happens-before relation. In other words, we now *know* that `y.store` happened before `y.load`, so the observable behavior must reflect that. `x.store` is sequenced-before `y.store` and `y.load` is sequenced before `x.load`. Due to the transitivity of happens-before, it now follows that `x.store` happens-before `x.load`. In other words, `x.load` *must* observe the value written by `x.store` (or some later value). That is the actual reason why `x.store` cannot be reordered past `y.store`, and also why `x.load` cannot be reordered before `y.load`. However, `z.store` and `z.load` can still be freely reordered.

Let's take a last look at the original code in question and see how the absence of a happens-before relation can result in incorrect code:

```
Thread 1:
... // use object
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  // branch not taken
}

Thread 2:
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  delete control_block_ptr;
}
```

Suppose the object in question looks something like this:

```
struct Object {
  ~Object() {
    if (foo) delete foo;
    ...
  }
  Foo* foo;
  ...
};
```

Then the code for Thread 2 could look like this:

```
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  // inlined control_block_ptr.~Object()
  auto f = control_block_ptr->foo;
  if (f) delete f;
  ...
}
```

Even though a release-operation usually prevents operations to be reordered *past* it, it is perfectly legal the reorder operations *before* it. So the code could be optimized like this:

```
auto f = control_block_ptr->foo;
if (control_block_ptr->refs.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release) == 1) {
  // inlined control_block_ptr.~Object()
  if (f) delete f;
  ...
}
```

So now we read `foo` before the `fetch_sub`, but that means we might read `foo` at a time when Thread 1 still uses the object (and potentially *writes* to `foo`).

Instruction reorderings by the compiler are rather simple ways to demonstrate how/why the memory model is relevant, but it is important to note that there are also other aspect that can affect the order in which code is executed or writes become visible, like out-of-order execution or peculiarities of the memory subsystem. So focusing on instruction reordering alone is not sufficient. Instead, it is important to understand that *above all is the concept of happens-before relations*.

By focusing on instruction reorderings we miss the bigger picture. If a certain instruction reordering would be problematic, then there must be an implicit requirement of a happens-before relation - and *that* is what we should focus on!

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Good catch! I have fixed the pseudocode accordingly.

Comment: "_The C++ standard says nothing about if or when instructions can be reordered._" Not only that: you simply *cannot express* the C/C++ MT semantics (or what passes for a semantic, as the semantics of MT programs are actually NOT defined properly, as the std writers have zero idea what a PL specification looks like) with just the possibility of re-orderings, as can easily be seen in a case where there is only one atomic op in each thread (thus no intra thread "ordering" issue) and the result is not guaranteed to be sequential.

Comment: But `fetch_sub`, being an RMW operation, always loads the **last value in the modification order**. Also, within a single thread happens-before is basically guaranteed by sequenced-before. Furthemore `memory_order_release` guarantees that no memory operation can move below it, so all memory operations must be completed before the `fetch_sub` within a single thread . So the `delete` can only run when previous threads already reached and completed their `fetch_sub`, which implies that they also completed their memory operations. Am I missing something?

Comment: Since `fetch_sub` always loads the last value in the modification order, `delete` can only run when other threads finished all access (which is guaranteed by their `fetch_sub` with `memory_order_release`).

Comment: @plasmacel "within a single thread happens-before is basically guaranteed by sequenced-before" not necessarily! The compiler is free to reorder instructions as long as it does not affect observable behavior (as-if rule). And the observable behavior _across threads_ is defined by means of the happens-before relation. It is correct that a RMW operation always observes the last value in the modification order, but this alone does not provide any guarantees about _surrounding_ operations.

Comment: `memory_order_release` by itself does not provide any guarantees about which reorderings can/can't be applied. However, a release-operation can synchronize-with an acquire-operation, and the resulting happens-before relation _does_ provide visibility guarantees. That is the _actual_ reason why no write before the release-operation can be reordered past it, because such a reordering would change the _observable behavior_. However, a release RMW cannot synchronize with another release RMW, so we would lack the happens-before relation.

Comment: And that is the reason why operations that are ordered _after_ a release-operation in source code order, _can be reordered_ so that they occur _before_ the release-operation. But that is exactly what we need to prevent here - the `delete` must happen _after_ the `fetch_sub`.

Comment: @mpoeter "The compiler is free to reorder instructions as long as it does not affect observable behavior (as-if rule)." This complies with the definition of happens-before, which is a property of the observable behavior as far as I know, i.e. the standard term happens-before doesn't mean actually executing before, but perceived happens-before. Now, how is this perceived behavior is not broken within the thread of the last `fetch_sub` if you run code of the *then* before evaluating the condition of the *if*? I'm trying to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @mpoeter These two statements also seem to be conflicting: 1. "`memory_order_release` by itself does not provide any guarantees about which reorderings can/can't be applied", 2. "That is the actual reason why no write before the release-operation can be reordered past".

Comment: @plasmacel I have updated my answer to provide more details - I hope this helps. Let me know if you still have any questions.